# how do i select the same row from one table for different values in another table + sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table values are as below

table 1

```
edition
-------
2001       
2002
2003
```

table 2

```
productid |  shortname
----------------------
185       |  jtic
```

The result should be

```
2001          185          jtic 
2002          185          jtic
2003          185          jtic
```

How can I achieve this? Tried with some joins . But not able to get it. As I am not a database developer, finding it hard. Can someone help?

Comment: Please show us what exactly you have tried so far. And by the way, you might want to post the tables separately. This format is quite confusing. I thought it was one table with three columns at first.

Comment: I have tried left outer join of t1 with t2 . but not getting desired output

Comment: posted tables separately

Comment: "tried left outer join of t1 with t2" does *not* "show us what exactly you have tried so far". Please edit your question with exact code including table defintions and select * from your tables, and explain why you wrote what you wrote. Also show us that info for some example in whatever reference you are using that does something like what you want, and explain why. Read and act on [mcve].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use CROSS JOIN method :

```
  SELECT edition , productid ,  shortname
  FROM table1
  CROSS JOIN table2
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Mansoors answer you can also use a shorter syntax:

```
SELECT edition , productid ,  shortname
FROM table1, table2
```